# Population ratio confidence interval

Tags: statistics

Let $x$ represent the number of defects from sample of size $n$. The possibility of defect occuring is $p$. Let $m$ represent the expected number of defects from sample of size $n$.  The 95% confidence interval is given as following:
$$\bar{x}-1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}<m<\bar{x}+1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Now I will divide this inequality by $n$. We know that $\bar{x}/n=\hat{p}$ and $m/n=p$. From binomial distribution, we know that $x \sim B(n, p)$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{npq} \simeq \sqrt{n\hat{p}\hat{q}}$. Thus,
$$\hat{p}-1.96\frac{\sqrt{\hat{p}\hat{q}}}{n}<p<\hat{p}+1.96\frac{\sqrt{\hat{p}\hat{q}}}{n}$$
However, this is different from the well-known equation,
$$\hat{p}-1.96\frac{\sqrt{\hat{p}\hat{q}}}{\sqrt{n}}<p<\hat{p}+1.96\frac{\sqrt{\hat{p}\hat{q}}}{\sqrt{n}}$$
I don't understand where the paradox occurs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: where did you get $\bar{x}-1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}<m<\bar{x}+1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have confused yourself by writing $\bar{x}$ rather than $x$

You in fact have a single binomial observation $x$, which has expectation $np$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{npq}$

Your normal approximation to a $95\%$ confidence interval would then be $$x-1.96\sqrt{n\frac{x}{n}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)} < np <x+1.96\sqrt{n\frac{x}{n}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)}$$ and dividing by $n$ gives $$\frac{x}{n}-1.96\sqrt{\frac{x}{n^2}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)} < p <\frac{x}{n}+1.96\sqrt{\frac{x}{n^2}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)}$$ while replacing $\frac x n$ with $\hat{p}$ would give your well-known result $$\hat{p}-1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}\hat{q}}{n}} < p <\hat{p}+1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}\hat{q}}{n}}$$